# Input field not reachable - Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have a md-list with the following content:

```
<md-list-item *ngIf="passwortEditable" class="input-list-item">
            <md-icon md-list-icon>lock</md-icon>
            <md-input-container class="margin-left-16">
              <input #inputAltesPasswort mdInput title="Aktuelles Passwort" type="password" placeholder="Aktuelles Passwort"
                     (keyup.enter)="savePasswort(inputAltesPasswort?.value, inputNeuesPasswort?.value,
                     inputPasswortWiederholung?.value)" (keyup.escape)="passwortEditable=false">
            </md-input-container>
          </md-list-item>
          <md-list-item *ngIf="passwortEditable" class="input-list-item">
            <md-icon md-list-icon>lock</md-icon>
            <md-input-container class="margin-left-16">
              <input #inputNeuesPasswort mdInput title="Neues Passwort" type="password" placeholder="Neues Passwort"
                     (keyup.enter)="savePasswort(inputAltesPasswort?.value, inputNeuesPasswort?.value,
                     inputPasswortWiederholung?.value)" (keyup.escape)="passwortEditable=false">
            </md-input-container>
          </md-list-item>
          <md-list-item *ngIf="passwortEditable" class="input-list-item">
            <md-icon md-list-icon>lock</md-icon>
            <md-input-container class="margin-left-16">
              <input #inputPasswortWiederholung mdInput title="Passwortwiederholung" type="password" placeholder="Neues Passwort wiederholen"
                     (keyup.enter)="savePasswort(inputAltesPasswort?.value, inputNeuesPasswort?.value,
                     inputPasswortWiederholung?.value)" (keyup.escape)="passwortEditable=false">
            </md-input-container>
          </md-list-item>
          <md-list-item *ngIf="passwortEditable">
            <button md-raised-button color="accent" (click)="savePasswort(inputAltesPasswort?.value, inputNeuesPasswort?.value,
               inputPasswortWiederholung?.value)" class="margin-left-20">ÜBERNEHMEN</button>
            <button md-raised-button  (click)="passwortEditable=false" class="margin-left-20">ABBRECHEN</button>
          </md-list-item>
```

In the `savePasswort` function I try to read out the values from three input fields. This worked well when I had all input fields in the same `md-list-item`. Now I splitted them off for styling reasons in a `md-list-item` each (how you can see above). But now, angular cannot access my input fields. I assume that the reason is, that they are "hidden" behind different `*ngIf`. Is there a solution to fix that?

Comment: Overal this look like a bad pratice. You have multiple duplicated code to fix your layout (it seems).

Comment: I'm not sure how I can simplify it. This is a password change form with a field for current password, new password an password repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution. The problem is the use of different *ngIf indeed. When I wrap the md-list-item in a div that is controlled bei an *ngIf it works.

Comment: This works when all input fields can be wrapped up in a div. But what could I do if  the different input fields are not next to each other in the HTML structure so that they cannot be wrapped by a single div?